# Get data from a firestore nested query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch the posts of a community and get the post maker data by making a nested query for each post so I made map's anonymous function as async so I've to return a promise and that's the problem, I want to return an object of values instead of a promise, how can I solve that?

```
export const getComPosts = (comId) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: POST_LIST_REQUEST })

        await firestore.collection('comPosts').where('comId', '==', comId).onSnapshot(snap => {
            const posts = snap.docs.map(async doc => {
                const { userId } = doc.data()

                const { avatar, displayName } = await (await firestore.collection('users').doc(userId).get()).data()

                return { ...doc.data(), avatar, displayName } // I wanna return this object directly not a promise
            })

            dispatch({ type: POST_LIST_RESPONSE, payload: posts })
        })
    } catch (e) {
        dispatch({ type: POST_LIST_FAIL, payload: e.message })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, all async function returns a promise, even if that's not what you return directly.  As soon as you label a function async, it's going to return a promise that's fulfilled with the data that you return from it.

Secondly, if you want to perform a query and get a single set of results, you shouldn't use `onSnapshot` for that.  That's only for persistent listeners that receive any number of document updates over time.  If your function is async, you can return only one object from it, and that's not compatible with `onSnapshot`.  `onSnapshot` doesn't return a promise that can be awaited.

Thirdly, you can't use async/await inside a `map()` lambda function effectively.  `map()` will not wait for the each await to complete before moving on to the next document in the array.

If you want a single set of results from a query, you should use `get()` instead of `onSnapshot()`.  This is illustrated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).  `get()` returns a promise which you can await.

Your solution is going to have to be structured more like this:

```
const snap = await firestore.collection('comPosts').where('comId', '==', comId).get()
const posts = []
for (const doc of snap.docs) {
    const { userId } = doc.data()
    const { avatar, displayName } = (await firestore.collection('users').doc(userId).get()).data()
    posts.push({ ...doc.data(), avatar, displayName })
}
return posts
```